# Blinking a creature equipped w Stitcher's Graft

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Any creature equipped with [Stitcher's Graft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStitcher%27s%5d%2b%5bGraft%5d) must be sacrificed when it's no longer attached. My question is do you sacrifice the creature exiled by a spell such as [Cloudshift](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCloudshift%5d) or will it just come back good as new?

Answer (score 5):

As rule 400.7 explains, the exiled creature is a new object:

> An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

Stitcher's Graft's third ability mentions "that permanent", which does not exist anymore, so it cannot be sacrificed.